# Showing that a strictly increasing function defined on some interval has a continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f$, which is defined on an interval $I$, is strictly increasing but not necessarily continuous (has at most finitely many jump discontinuities).  Show that $f$ has a continuous inverse.

In my old topology notes, there is a problem that seems really similar:

Suppose $g$ from $E_1$ to $E_1$ is invertible and continuous.  Show that $g$ is a homeomorphism (i.e. show that $g^{-1}$ is continuous).  For this problem, it was enough to show that $g$ maps open sets to open sets.  That is, $g(a, b) = (g(a), g(b))$ where $(a, b)$ is open in the domain and $(g(a), g(b))$ is open in the range.  Would the same thing work for $f$ given that $f$ is not necessarily continuous?

Comment: The issue to think about here is the *domain* of that inverse function and what it means to be continuous on it. You do need to know that a strictly increasing function must be continuous away from its discontinuities (necessarily jump discontinuities, yes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=f(I)$. As $f$ is strictly in creasing, it is certainly injective, and it is by definition surjective to $Y$. Hence there exist an inverse map $g\colon Y\to I$ (so $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_I$ and $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_Y$). To show that $g$ is continuous, we need to show that the inverse image $g^{-1}(U)$ of every open set $U$ is open. It suffices to consider the case that $U$ is an open interval $(a,b)$. Of course, $g^{-1}(a,b)=(f(a),f(b))\cap Y$, which is open in $Y$. (The - literally - boundary case that $U$ contains a boundary point of $I$ is slightly, but kust slightly different)

Comment: why $g^{-1}(a,b)=(f(a),f(b))\cap Y$? what if $(a,b)$ is not a subset of $I$? then $f(a), f(b)$ might not defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this without using topology, since Bartle and Sherbert's textbook on introductory real analysis introduces continuity without having had first introduced anything without topology. This will make the thread useful because it will also be accessible to the thousands of students using this textbook in addition to the ones who are using elementary topology. Here goes:

I got my idea for the proof by GRAPHING the scenario. In real analysis, ALWAYS graph the scenario when looking for a proof. The proof will suddenly become obvious.

Upon graphing, I noticed that for $\epsilon>0$, and an arbitrary c in Domain($f^{-1}$), if U is the corresponding $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f^{-1}$(c), and a, b are the endpoints of U, then by f's strictly monotone and non-invariant nature, f maps U into an open interval K, whose endpoints are f(a) and f(b); and whether these endpoints are upper or lower depends on whether f is increasing or decreasing: If f is decreasing, the endpoints are reversed in their f-image. If f is increasing, they are preserved.

Notice that it is not necessarily true that K will be centered around c. Indeed, if f's image is given by $e^x$ for each x in it's domain, then K is not centered at c (GRAPH it and see). This means we can't just use $\delta=\frac{1}{2}(\left |f(a)-f(b)\right |)$. Do you see the obvious choice though? It will be the minimum distance of c from an endpoint of K; but we have to take care of some things first to prove it.

It is possible that f doesn't map U *onto* K. Possibly there were points of discontinuity in U that cause a gap in (i.e. disconnect) K. Also, it is possible that elements in Domain(f), and not in U, map into K and fill in a subset of any of these gaps. GRAPH this! You will see it too.

This poses a problem that needs to be worked out before selecting the obvious choice of $\delta$. Which is, min{$\left |f(a)-c\right |,\left |f(b)-c\right|$}. It needs to be shown that none of the points in $V_\delta(c)\cap Range(f)$ map to somewhere outside of U in the domain.

From looking at the graph, I came up with the following idea:

To prove $f^{-1}$ maps any elements of the range within K into U,
let K' denote $K\cap Range(f)$. At this point, we're not sure whether f maps U onto K', even though K' is a subset of the range. For instance, how do we know that the f-image of U doesn't miss some element y of K', that is then filled in by something in the domain outside of U? For example, suppose f had a point of discontinuity within U, and the f-image of this point landed extremely far away from K' (well outside of it's bounds, i.e. K's endpoints); but there was also some x outside of U whose f-image filled in this hole. Then $f^{-1}$ would map y outside of U This would be a problem.

To prove this doesn't happen, let y be in K'. Since K'$\subseteq Range(f)$, we know there is some pre-image x= of y, in the domain, whose f-image strikes y. Obviously, then, y=$f^{-1}$(x). Suppose in this case that x is outside of U. This means it is *either above or below* both of U's bondaries, a and b.

The strict monotone and non-invariant nature of f can be used to show that, in either case, x's f-image, f(x), will lie either below or above both f(a) and f(b), two upper and lower bounds for K, and hence f(x) cannot lie in K'. This is a contradiction since y is in K', and y=f(x). Thus we can rest assured that x, and hence $f^{-1}$(y) does not lie outside of U: that is, $$f^{-1}\textrm{(K')}\subseteq U.$$

All we need to do now is choose  $\delta$ so that $V_\delta(c)\cap Range(f)\subseteq K$'. This, in turn, will ensure that $f^{-1}(V\cap Range(f))\subseteq U$

So choose the obvious $\delta$: $\delta=$min{$\left |f(a)-c\right |,\left |f(b)-c\right|$}, and let V denote it's corresponding c-neighborhood.

This choice of $\delta$ is sufficiently small to keep $V\cap Range(f)$ inside of K', because V lies entirely between f(a) and f(b) and hence is merely an inclusion of K intersected with Range(f); which means it is necessarily an inclusion of K'. That is, $V\cap Range(f)\subseteq K'$.

Since $f^{-1}(K')\subseteq U$, we know $f^{-1}(V\cap Range(f))\subseteq U$

So we've now shown that, for arbitrary c in Domain($f^{-1}$), and any neighborhood U of $f^{-1}$(c), there is a neighborhood V of c so that $f^{-1}(V\cap Range(f))\subseteq U$. Thus, by the neighborhood definition of continuity, $f^{-1}$ is continuous over its entire domain; and, thus, is a continuous function.

Q.E.D.

Adam V. Nease